# show array item on blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**Arrays:**

```
[
    {"id":1,"group":"post","name":"Mi","value":"x3 poco"},
    {"id":2,"group":"post","name":"iPhone","value":"14 pro"},
    {"id":3,"group":"post","name":"Nokia","value":"C5"},
    {"id":4,"group":"post","name":"Dell","value":"15 insp"}
    .
    .
    .
]
```

**IndexController.php** file:

```
$post = Post::all();
return view('index', compact('post'));
```

**index.blade.php** file:

```
Post Name: "{{ $post->name['iPhone']->value }}"
```

I want to show the **output** as below:

```
Post Name: "14 pro"
```

But **error** is showing:

```
Error: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Comment: foreach on the collection inside the blade.

Comment: Be very cognizent that this answer is right, but the question is very wrong. Author, you are getting everything and then filtering on PHP what you want... that is absolutely bad on PHP, so the asnwer is right on SO but is very wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `where` on the collection to search by name:

```
Post Name: "{{ $post->where('name', 'iPhone')->first()?->value }}"
```

The question mark is in case there is no item with the name you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays, so `name` is inside a numeric index...

This:

```json
[
    {"id":1,"group":"post","name":"Mi","value":"x3 poco"},
    {"id":2,"group":"post","name":"iPhone","value":"14 pro"},
    {"id":3,"group":"post","name":"Nokia","value":"C5"},
    {"id":4,"group":"post","name":"Dell","value":"15 insp"}
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Is this on PHP:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'group' => 'post',
        'name' => 'Mi',
        'value' => 'x3 poco',
    ],
    [
        // ...
    ],
];
```

So, you have to iterate it like this:

```html
Posts:
@foreach ($post as $item)
    Post Name: "{{ $item->value }}"
@endforeach
```